# Detecting backspace key press

Tags: java, filter, document

Is there a way to detect when the backspace key on the keyboard has been pressed, using a document filter? [The following is an edited code extract from here](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

For Example

```
public class IntFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    boolean trueFalse = true;
    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                             String string, AttributeSet attr)
            throws BadLocationException {

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(string);
        for (int i = buffer.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char ch = buffer.charAt(i);
            if (!Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                buffer.deleteCharAt(i);
                trueFalse = false;
            }
            /*
            else if (backspace pressed)
            {
                trueFalse = true;
            }
            */
            else{
                trueFalse = true;
            }
        }
        super.insertString(fb, offset, buffer.toString(), attr);
    }

    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb,
                        int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (length > 0) fb.remove(offset, length);
        insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to use a document filter?

Comment: @NabeelOmer For this question yes. In the actual program, I'm currently experimenting with a DocumentListener

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the backspace key won't trigger the `insertString()` method. It should rather trigger the `remove()` method (only when text is actually removed, which is not the case when the caret is at the beginning of the text for example).

But you can detect any keystroke using a `KeyListener` ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)). Here's how you would detect the backspace key:

```
public class KeyEventDemo implements KeyListener {

    /** Handle the key typed event from the text field. */
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    /** Handle the key-pressed event from the text field. */
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

    /** Handle the key-released event from the text field. */
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE){
             // Do something...
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How would you make it so the backspace key triggered the remove()? When I tried to add that in, it got called every time any key was pressed not just the backspace key?

Comment: `remove()` is called when *any* key is pressed? If so, there's probably something wrong. `remove()` is called when text is removed, which can happen when you press backspace, or *Suppr*, or when you press any key while some text is selected (which first removes text, and then inserts the new text).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know no way t detect that in DocumentFilter.

If you select a char and press DEL it's the same as you press BACKSPACE. Offset and length of deleted text is identical.

Instead you can define your [KeyBinding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for BACKSPACE processing and place your code there.

Comment: And in this example what do you suggest I add the keybinding to?